# How to use LaTex write this expression?

Tags: equations

How to use LaTex represent this expression:

[image]

Comment: I'd use `\int_{0}^{1} 1 \,dx= x   bigg\vert_{0}^1 = 1-0=1`

Comment: thanks, this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more or less

```
\[
  \int_{0}^{1} 1\,dx = x  \big\vert_{0}^1 = 1-0=1
\]
```

Note that I see no reason to make the vertical line as large as the integral.

Also note for your next question, please show what you had so far, not images of what you want. We are not really a "please do this for me" service.